# What's the Objective-C + Cocoa equivalent of Java + Swing's Event Dispatch Thread?

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, swing, cocoa

I'm an experienced Java Swing programmer. We have a mantra: "all UI work must be performed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)."

I assume Cocoa has a similar mantra. What is Cocoa's equivalent of Java's EDT? And how do I make a block of code run on that equivalent?

If it is significant, I'm using Cocoa for an **OS X app**, not for an iOS ap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //UI updates on main thread
});
```

Comment: Yes. And the `Main Dispatch Queue` executes tasks on that thread.